# Get Angles from ModelViewMatrix

Tags: c++, opengl

I have the following matrix in a game I'm reverse engineering to see how it works.

I managed to capture this matrix when a model is rendered:

```
     0.999971,     0.003148,     -0.006994,  0.000000
     0.000000,     0.911863,      0.410494,  0.000000
     0.006903,    -0.410485,      0.911844,  0.000000
-25014.388672, 11944.956055, -19475.357422,  1.000000
```

I started calculating the angle using the following:

```
Point CalculateRotatation(float ModelView[16])
{
    Point Result;
    Result.X = atan2(ModelView[9], ModelView[10]) * (180 / PI);
    Result.Y = atan2(-ModelView[8], ModelView[9]) * (180 / PI);
    Result.Z = atan2(ModelView[4], ModelView[0]) * (180 / PI);
    return Result;
}
```

I was following: http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. The game does not using OpenGL-ES but I'm not sure that it matters.

Can any of you tell me if I'm on the right path or if my Calculate function is correct?
The Y-value seems to be wrong. I know there are many threads like this and I looked through them but they don't seem to be doing what I have. They are using dot products and cross products. I just need confirmation or a little help.

**EDIT:** I know this much:

I know the calculations for the X and Y rotations are correct. If I change my character's view from left to right, the Z increases/decreases. If I change my character's view height, the X increases/decreases. The Y however I don't know if it is right or how to get it.. I have this diagram:
[image]

Comment: do you know the model and view matrix?

Comment: Make sure to double check column-major/row-major, that's always a place for discrepancies.

Comment: I don't know the two matrices separately. I updated OP with everything I know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extracting fixed angles from rotation matrix can have multiple answers because it is involving inverse trigonometric and a square root. For example, if the rotation sequence is x-y-z (with row vector system), the formula is like below.

```
AngleX = atan2(m11, m22)
AngleY = atan2(-m02, sqrt(m00^2 + m01^2))
AngleZ = atan2(m01, m00)
```

But, this is not the end of the story. I'm sure that [this article](https://d3cw3dd2w32x2b.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/euler-angles.pdf) will help you find a better way. Good luck!

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do :) Can you help me with one thing. My friend said the exact same thing as you. He did the same thing as you: http://pastebin.com/ngusJifF

Except the indices X, Y are swapped. I think what you are doing with the 2D matrix is the same thing I did with a 1D matrix.